Запуск программ c использованием BAT файл
такая ситуация
Хочу что бы при запуска BAT файла закрывалась определённая программа и запускалась игра из библиотеки Steam, и при закрытии игры закрытая программа запускалась заново.
Вот пример:
taskkill /f /im Dock_64.exe  
"C:\Users\abuda\Desktop\Dota 2.url" 
# ( работает только так, если указать путь напрямую к ярлыку то тогда игры запускается без античита и играть невозможно)  
start F:\Steam\steamapps\common\MyDockFinder\Dock_64.exe

Вот что я хочу
что бы команда закрывала программу и запускала игру и при закрытии игры программа снова открывалась.
Помогите пожалуйста)
Я нашел еще такое решение но хотелось бы довести то автоматизма
taskkill /f /im Dock_64.exe
"C:\Users\abuda\Desktop\Dota 2.url"
pause
start F:\Steam\steamapps\common\MyDockFinder\Dock_64.exe


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Обычно программам нужно находиться непосредственно в базовой директории, чтобы это осуществить. Добавьте строку с переходом в каталог программы, если у меня программа в C:\Program Files\MyGame то запустив командную строку с диска С а дам такую команду: cd /d "C:\Program Files\MyGame" Эту команду нужно выполнить самой первой.

Здесь есть проблема, на мой взгляд, связанная с тем, что .cmd должен оставаться в работе, пока Вы играете. Могут быть очень неожиданные эффекты. Я предлагаю не абсолютно рабочее решение для двух абстрактных программ, а возможно рабочее (для .cmd, Windows 11):
@echo off
taskkill /f /im program1.exe
start /wait program2.exe
start program1.exe


И да, запускают программы не ЧЕРЕЗ, а С ИСПОЛЬЗОВАНИЕМ (по-русски если говорить)

не подходит,  оно недожимается закрытия игры и запускает ее сразу же

Я подправил. Было в коде лишнее. Для простеньких приложений типа notepad (program2 в данном примере) и cleanmgr.exe (program1 в данном примере) работает. Но в более сложных случаях, когда один поток запускает другой, что часто бывает в играх, скорее всего работать не сможет.

Уже лучше! но! код не дожидается закрытия игры что бы вернуть другу программу, он закрывает и открывает ее сразу же, я там сверху пост подправил и написал вариант который у меня более удачный получился как будто /wait не работает

Я ничего не понял из написанного в последнем сообщении. Для простых приложений, примеры которых я показал, работает как надо. Если был запущен cleanmgr.exe, он будет выгружен и запущен  notepad. Как только происходит выход из  notepad, сразу же запускается cleanmgr.exe. Все идут по очереди. Как я уже говорил, для простеньких приложений это работает. А вот для монстров, состоящих из многих потоков, скорее всего нет. Больше у меня нет идей.

Спасибо нейросетям! Вот вариант, который реально работает:
@echo off
taskkill /f /im Dock_64.exe ( Процесс который нужно закрыть)
start steam://rungameid/570 ( Код игры из стима которую нужно запустить)

timeout /t 10

:waitForGameClose
tasklist | find "dota2.exe" >nul
if errorlevel 1 (
    goto continue
) else (
    timeout /t 2 >nul
    goto waitForGameClose
)

:continue
start F:\Steam\steamapps\common\MyDockFinder\Dock_64.exe 

